# anteponer un dato para validar antes de ser insertado

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Estoy tratando de validar si el campo **Codigo** contiene el prefijo que se debe usar al crear un nuevo registro, estoy tratando de crear el siguiente trigger el cual me debe validar si el documento que va a registrar contenga ese prefijo que se debe usar .

```
alter  trigger Sp_Validr_SN
on tblsocio_negocios for insert, update , delete

as
declare @codigo nvarchar(20)

    select @codigo =  codigo from tblsocio_negocios 

        if (@codigo = 'C-') begin

         RAISERROR ('No se puede realizar esta accion.',
                                             -- Message text.  
               16,                           -- Severity.  
               1                             -- State.  
               ) 
end
```

Ejemplo 
Si el nuevo registro contiene **C-12345678** lo deje guardar, en caso de que no tenga el **C-** no lo deje insertar.
espero me haya dado a entender

¿Alguna recomendacion?,
¿Cómo mas podria hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el trigger lo puedes hacer de esta manera. Te expongo un ejemplo con la tabla, pero creada con una sola columna código, ya que para el mismo es suficiente.

```
create table tblsocio_negocios (codigo nvarchar(20))
go

create trigger Tr_Validr_SN
on tblsocio_negocios for insert

as
Declare @cod int = 0;
;with cte as (
    select case when SUBSTRING(codigo,1,2) = N'c-' then 0 else 1 end as cod
from inserted
    )
select @cod = sum(cod) from cte;

if @cod >0
begin

     RAISERROR ('No se puede realizar esta accion.',
                                         -- Message text.  
           16,                           -- Severity.  
           1                             -- State.  
           ) ;
    rollback tran;
end

go
```

El trigger, solo aplica para insert no para update ni delete. Tampoco parece del todo adecuado que el nombre empiece por sp, en todo caso más bien por tr.

Cuando se trabaja con triggers hay que tener muy en cuenta que no se tiene porque insertar una sola fila, que pueden ir varias en la misma sentencia.

Esto funciona del siguiente modo, en la entrada del trigger, lo que se hace es un case por cada uno de los registros que tenga la pseudo-tabla inserted que es la contenedora de la información que se inserta. Si el resultado de ese substring es un "c-" entonces para esa fila, tiene un 0, en caso contrario un 1. En la salida de la tabla de expresión común sumamos, los valores de esa columna y se los asignamos a la variable @cod

Luego con el if evaluamos si la variable tiene un valor mayor que 0 entonces alguna de las filas es erronea, y mostramos el mensaje, tal cual estaba en el ejemplo, y deshacemos la inserción.

```
insert into tblsocio_negocios (codigo)
values
('a');
go
```

Mensaje 50000, nivel 16, estado 1, procedimiento Tr_Validr_SN, línea 16 [línea de inicio de lote 28]
No se puede realizar esta accion.
Mens. 3609, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 29
La transacción terminó en el desencadenador. Se anuló el lote.

```
insert into tblsocio_negocios (codigo)
values
(N'c-12');
go
```

(1 fila afectada)

```
insert into tblsocio_negocios (codigo)
values
(N'c-13'),
(N'c-14'),
(N'c-15'),
(N'a-16');
go
```

Mensaje 50000, nivel 16, estado 1, procedimiento Tr_Validr_SN, línea 16 [línea de inicio de lote 36]
No se puede realizar esta accion.
Mens. 3609, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 37
La transacción terminó en el desencadenador. Se anuló el lote.

```
insert into tblsocio_negocios (codigo)
values
(N'c-13'),
(N'c-14'),
(N'c-15'),
(N'c-16');
go
```

(4 filas afectadas)

```
Select * from tblsocio_negocios;
```

c-12
c-13
c-14
c-15
c-16

(5 filas afectadas)

No obstante, me parece mucho más apropiado utilizar una constraint como te ha propuesto @Kevin Restrepo, pero con alguna variante, puesto que no debe de ser like '%C-' sino lo contrario 'C-%'.

En este caso yo lo implementaría así:

```
drop trigger Tr_Validr_SN
go
```

Elimino el trigger, para aplicar la constraint

```
ALTER TABLE tblsocio_negocios 
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_TBLSOCIO_NEGOCIOS_CODIGO CHECK (CODIGO LIKE N'c-%')
GO

insert into tblsocio_negocios (codigo)
values
(N'C-17');
GO
```

(1 fila afectada)

```
insert into tblsocio_negocios (codigo)
values
(N'A-17');
GO
```

Mens. 547, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 64
Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción CHECK 'CK_TBLSOCIO_NEGOCIOS_CODIGO'. El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos 'xxxx', tabla 'dbo.tblsocio_negocios', column 'codigo'.
Se terminó la instrucción.

Con los mismos ejemplos en insertar varias filas a la vez.

```
insert into tblsocio_negocios (codigo)
values
(N'c-18'),
(N'c-19'),
(N'c-20'),
(N'a-20');
go

insert into tblsocio_negocios (codigo)
values
(N'c-18'),
(N'c-19'),
(N'c-20'),
(N'c-21');
go

select * from tblsocio_negocios;
```

c-12
c-13
c-14
c-15
c-16
C-17
c-18
c-19
c-20
c-21

(10 filas afectadas)

El resultado es el mismo.

[Tablas de expresión común](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con la funcion `CHECK`

```
ALTER TABLE tblsocio_negocios ADD CHECK (codigo like '%C-');
```

Prueba  y me comentas

Comment: Realizando la funcion que me sugieres si altera, pero al momento de realizar la validacion no da resultado como tal, quizas este haciendo algo mal, podrias regalar algun ejemplo  para la validacion?

Answer (score 0):

Tomando en consideración tu ejemplo y verificando que la letra siempre esta dentro de la primera posición tu puedes utilizar el siguiente ejemplo y modificar el procedimiento almacenado que inserta en la tabla de socio y el mismo procedimiento validara si cumple la informacion o si no cumple, y de esta manera de ahorras tener un trigger para controlar eso y tendrias mejor performance en tu db

```
create procedure Socios
@Codigo varchar(20)
as
if  left( @Codigo,1) <> 'C'
begin
/*en este caso si el registro es diferente de la letra C permitira insertarlo*/
insert into
socio(@Codigo)
values
(@Codigo)
end
else
-- en este caso si el registro que se esta tratando de insetar no cumple el procedimiento almacenado no ejecutar
--ninguna accion
begin 
return
end
```

Comment: De ante mano gracias por tomarse el tiempo de analizarlo y copiarlo aca como ejemplo, estaba mirando la respuesta que me diste , lo estoy probando con algunos ajustes que le hice pero aun me deja insertar los registros 
y no esta cumpliendo con la funcion de se requiere

Comment: Si alguien ingresa un registro **C-123456789** ese registro se debe guardar normal 
pero si ingresan **123456789** no deberia dejar registrar el dato